# Replacing secret with certificate in Azure app registration

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am currently using a client secret with an Azure app registration to access an Azure Media service from an App Service. I want to replace the client secret with a certificate as the certificate will last longer. I have successfully generated a certificate and uploaded it to the app registration.

Using the client secret seems straight forward. I create environment variables (in the app service configuration or local.settings.json) for the app registration client ID, app registration client secret and tenant ID and then use the following code:

```
private async Task<ServiceClientCredentials> GetCredentialsAsync(string aadClientId, string aadSecret, string aadTenantId)
{

    ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(aadClientId, aadSecret);
    return await ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(aadTenantId, clientCredential, 
     ActiveDirectoryServiceSettings.Azure);
}
```

How do I change this code to use the certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I created an **Azure AD Application** and uploaded a certificate:

[image]

To generate the access token using certificate, you can declare the below parameters in your **`app.settings`** file:

```cs
"AzureAd": {
"Scope":"https://graph.microsoft/.default",
"Instance":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
"Domain":"XXX.onmicrosoft.com",
"TenantId":"YourTenantID",
"ClientId":"ClientID",

"ClientCertificates": [
{
"SourceType":"KeyVault",
"KeyVaultUrl":"https://xxx.vault.azure.net",
"KeyVaultCertificateName":"certName"
}
]
},
```

You can refer this [**blog**](https://damienbod.com/2020/10/01/implement-azure-ad-client-credentials-flow-using-client-certificates-for-service-apis/) by *damienbod* to know how generate the access token in detail.

I tried to **generate the access token** in Postman by using parameters like below:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:clientId
client_assertion_type:urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
client_assertion:client_assertion
```

[image]

**References:**

[Azure AD OAuth client credential flow with certificate by Nicola Delfino](https://nicolgit.github.io/azure-ad-oauth-client-credential-flow-certificate-walk-through/)

[App that calls MSGraph with a certificate by christosmatskas](https://cmatskas.com/create-a-net-core-deamon-app-that-calls-msgraph-with-a-certificate/)